# DataTable Column to String Array in Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, autocomplete, datatable

I am working with DataTable Column, I want to fetch a single column of datatable to String array and then wanted to assign to **AutoCompleteStringCollection** object. at the moment I am populating 'AutoCompleteStringCollection' using a loop, but if I have more then 500 rows, it takes time. I want to do this with out loop. can any body suggest a better quicker way.

```
Dim autocomp As New AutoCompleteStringCollection
        For index As Integer = 0 To unionTable.Rows.Count - 1
            autocomp.Add(unionTable.Rows(index)(1).ToString())
        Next
```

I want to do without loop, help please

After a little struggle I managed to do this.with .Net 3.5 framework

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Dim table1 As DataTable = New DataTable("Test")
        table1.Columns.Add("name")
        table1.Columns.Add("id")
        table1.Rows.Add("Abb", 1)
        table1.Rows.Add("Killers", 2)

        Dim allAutoCompletes = From row In table1.AsEnumerable()
                       Let autoComplete = row.Field(Of String)(0)
                       Select autoComplete
        Dim autoCompleteString As String() = allAutoCompletes.ToArray()
        Dim x As String = ""
        Dim autocomp As New AutoCompleteStringCollection
        autocomp.AddRange(autoCompleteString)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You always have to use a loop. But you can use LINQ which looks nicer:

```
Dim allAutoCompletes = From row In unionTable.AsEnumerable()
                       Let autoComplete = row.Field(Of String)(1)
                       Select autoComplete 
Dim autoCompleteStringCollection As String() = allAutoCompletes.ToArray()
```

If you want a `List(Of String)` use `ToList`.

Here's the same as above in method syntax, use what you find more readable:

```
Dim autoCompleteStringCollection As String() = unionTable.AsEnumerable().
    Select(Function(r) r.Field(Of String)(1)).
    ToArray()
```

Comment: but this error: 'AsEnumerable' is not a member of 'System.Data.DataTable'

Comment: You have to use >= .NET 3.5 and add `Imports System.Linq`. You also have to add a reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` to your project and it should be ok.

Comment: So have you added a   reference to the `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` dll?

Comment: No I cannot, because I have to change other things if I am adding this reference.

Comment: @DareDevil: i don't understand what other things you have to change. However, i think you could use `unionTable.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow)()` instead of `AsEnumerable`.

Comment: I read at a blog that if we use this reference then every object of DataTable needs to create using "using" statement, That's why I don't want to add

Comment: @DareDevil: that's nonsense.

Comment: boss let me try in test project, thanks for your kind suggestion and help.

Comment: @DareDevil: you don't need `using` on a `DataTable` because it doesn't use unmanaged resources. It implements `IDisposable` because of it's designer-drag/drop capabilities. By using `AsEnumerable` you don't change that fact. Of course you need to _execute_ this ["lazy"-query](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/215877/is-linq-more-efficient-than-it-appears-on-the-surface) as every LINQ query, for example by using `For Each`, `CopyToDataTable`, `ToList`, `ToArray` or another method.

Comment: Oh I just figure out, The project on which i was working is based upon .net 3.0 that's why, Now I have created a Test Application and used it. It working .

Comment: @DareDevil: that's why i mentioned >= 3.5 in my first comment. Note that i've edited my last comment.

Answer (score 0):

The code from Rango works great for me.  Here's the code as an extension which can be placed in any public module and used by adding "Imports Extensions" in the class you wish to enable it for:

```
Public Module Extensions
    ''' <summary>Build string array from specified column in DataTable.</summary>
    ''' <returns>String()</returns>
    <Extension()>
    Public Function ColumnToStringArray(ByVal dataTable As DataTable, columnIndex As Integer) As String()
        Dim allAutoCompletes = From row In dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                           Let autoComplete = row.Field(Of String)(columnIndex)
                           Select autoComplete
        Return allAutoCompletes.ToArray()
    End Function
End Module
```

Use:

```
Dim dt as DataTable = (function that returns datatable)
TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(dt.ColumnToStringArray(0))
```